# Getting all occurrences of a day in month

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

i have the first day and last day of the month, the length of the current month i'm looking for a function that will give me all the appearances of any day in this month, i've seen some functions that gives the next occurrence but i want to be able to enter any day and see all is occurrences .. i guess it will be some kind of loop..i'm working on it as we speek but any help would be great..

```
$scope.recurrenceFields.by_year_day=$filter('date')($scope.fields.times.dateStart, 'yyyy');
$scope.recurrenceFields.by_month=$filter('date')($scope.fields.times.dateStart, 'M');
    var correntDay = new Date();
                           var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(correntDay.getFullYear(), correntDay.getMonth()+1, 0);
                           var firstDayOfMonth = new Date(correntDay.getFullYear(), correntDay.getMonth(), 1);
                           function daysInMonth(month,year) {
                                return new Date($filter('date')($scope.fields.times.dateStart, 'yyyy'), $scope.recurrenceFields.by_month, 0).getDate();
                            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what "*all the appearances of any day in this month*" means, but the following function returns all the occurrences of a particular day in a month given year, month and day number.

```js
/* @param {number} year - calendar year
 ** @param {number} month - calendar month: 1-Jan, 2-Feb, etc.
 ** @param {number} dayNumber - day number: 0-Sunday, 1-Monday, etc.
 ** @returns {Array} Dates for all days in month of dayNumber
 */
function getAllDaysInMonth(year, month, dayNumber) {
  var d = new Date(year, --month, 1);
  var dates = [];
  var daysToFirst = (dayNumber + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7;
  var firstOf = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + daysToFirst));

  while (firstOf.getMonth() == month) {
    dates.push(new Date(+firstOf));
    firstOf.setDate(firstOf.getDate() + 7);
  }
  return dates;
}

// Return array of all Thursdays in July 2015
console.log(getAllDaysInMonth(2015, 7, 4));
// [Thu 02 Jul 2015,
//  Thu 09 Jul 2015,
//  Thu 16 Jul 2015,
//  Thu 23 Jul 2015,
//  Thu 30 Jul 2015]

// Get all Tuesdays in February 2000
console.log(getAllDaysInMonth(2000, 2, 2));
// [Tue 01 Feb 2000,
//  Tue 08 Feb 2000,
//  Tue 15 Feb 2000,
//  Tue 22 Feb 2000,
//  Tue 29 Feb 2000]

// Get all Sundays in December 2015
console.log(getAllDaysInMonth(2015, 12, 0));
// [Sun 06 Dec 2015,
//  Sun 13 Dec 2015,
//  Sun 20 Dec 2015,
//  Sun 27 Dec 2015]
```

Comment: i am using angular and i end up changing this line into this.. var daysToFirst = (($filter('date')($scope.fields.times.dateStart, 'd'))-1) % 7;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this service :

```
angular.module('myApp.services')
    .factory('dateUtils', function () {
        return {
            getIntervals: function (startTimestamp, endTimestamp, interval) {
                if(!angular.isNumber(startTimestamp) || !angular.isNumber(endTimestamp) || !angular.isNumber(interval) || startTimestamp===0 || endTimestamp===0) {
                    return [];
                }
                var intervals = [];
                var currentPeriod = startTimestamp;
                while (currentPeriod <= endTimestamp) {
                    intervals.push(currentPeriod);
                    var currentPeriodDate = new Date(currentPeriod);
                    currentPeriodDate.setDate(currentPeriodDate.getDate() + interval);
                    currentPeriod = currentPeriodDate.getTime();
                }
                return intervals;
            }
        };
    });
```

If you want all day between two dates, just use the service :

```
dateUtils.getIntervals(startDate, endDate, 1);
```